# Record Twilio Autopilot Conversations

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio Autopilot with Programmable Voice as Input Channel and I would like to record the entire conversation that the client has with the robot.

Where and how can I do it?

I'm using a twiML bin that redirects to the Autopilot URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Redirect method="POST">[autopilot url]</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To record the call without the `<Record>` TwiML verb, you could

1. Serve with the AP [connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect) verb `<Response> <Connect> <Autopilot>`...
2. Use the Call SID received in the response to that and [use the call recording controls API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource) to start recording the call.

Alternatively, you could use the `Moment` package in a Twilio function that is redirected from an Autopilot task.

For the task you want to record user input for, your Autopilot task code may look like this:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "your-task-name",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": {
                            "say": "What's your first name?"
                        },
                        "name": "first_name",
                        "type": "Twilio.FIRST_NAME"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": {
                            "say": "How many people would you like the reservation to be for?"
                        },
                        "name": "number",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": "https://your-function-url.twil.io/your-function-name"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After redirecting to the Twilio Function, you could write some Node.js code with the Moment module that may look like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const moment = require('moment');
    let responseObject = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
    let first_name = memory.twilio.collected_data.your-task-name.answers.first_name.answer || 'to whom it may concern';
    let number = memory.twilio.collected_data.your-task-name.answers.number.answer;
    let message = "Ok " + first_name + "You said your group is of size " + number + "Thank you for booking with us";
    ResponseObject = {
        "actions":[
        { "say": { "speech": message } }
    ]};
    callback(null, responseObject);
}
```

The code above saves the user's answers to each question your Autopilot assistant asks, expecting different types of responses. These [Built-in Field Types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/built-in-field-types) include numbers, yes or no answers, dates, times, first names, last names, emails, months, US states, countries, cities, days of the week, currencies, languages, and more. You can also keep track of the question the Autopilot assistant asks in each Autopilot task.

There's more details in this [Deep Table tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/tutorials/deep-table-restaurant-assistant) and this [Facebook Messenger bot blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-facebook-messenger-bot-with-twilio-autopilot-functions-and-sendgrid-in-node-js) (different communication platform, same code to parse user input.) Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in a Twilio Function but it returns an errors saying that "twiml.connect is not a function":
`exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
 twiml.connect().autopilot('UA40e846f1f521c2640606606a224fc6aa');
 twilioClient.calls(event.CallSid).recordings.create().then(recording => console.log(recording.sid));
    
    callback(null, twiml );
};`

Comment: Are your Twilio credentials configured correctly to use `getTwilioClient()` as mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation? I'd maybe try using this code from the Connect docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect#autopilot):


`const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const response = new VoiceResponse();
const connect = response.connect();
connect.autopilot('UAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');`

Comment: unfortunately i'm still getting the "response.connect is not a function" error, even after checking the "Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN" in the Functions configuration panel.

Comment: Try updating your Twilio helper library to a more recent version as this is a new functionality!

Comment: @lizziepika i'm getting below error (500 error) while starting the record using the callSid